# i can't use IF selection with 2 condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can I fix this?

my code:

```
if (exists (select OperationDocumentReportExamCode from OperationDocumentReportExam where OperationDocumentReportExamCode = @CODE) AND @OVERRIDE IS '0')
  Begin  
   Select 0 as Result  
  End
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IF (@OVERRIDE = 0 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM   operationdocumentreportexam 
                WHERE  operationdocumentreportexamcode = @CODE)) 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT 0 [Result] 
  END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IF EXISTS
(  SELECT 1 FROM OperationDocumentReportExam
   WHERE OperationDocumentReportExamCode = @CODE
) AND @OVERRIDE = 0
Begin
   SELECT 0 AS Result  
End
```

Comment: @KentgiTomo, no need of extra braces '(' and no need of `AND` outside `exists` block.

Comment: if i put AND inside the EXIST, i can't override the query do the else statement

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

Just modified your query a little:

```
if exists (select OperationDocumentReportExamCode from OperationDocumentReportExam where OperationDocumentReportExamCode = @CODE) AND @OVERRIDE = '0'
  Begin  
   Select 0 as Result  
  End
```